# Casting a void pointer to char* in order to do pointer arithmetic

Tags: c

In this video, taken from Stanford's CS107 lecture, the professor seems to state that casting a void* to a char* will do the same thing in terms of arithmetic as casting it to an unsigned long.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eR4rxnM7Lc&t=44m30s

The part in question goes from 44:30 to around 46:00

He says they are "both 4-byte figures"

I understand casting the void* to a char*, because it will assume arithmetic is sizeof(char) = 1.
But I don't get how you could do the same thing by casting it to an unsigned long* because the arithmetic will be in units of 4.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not `unsigned long *` - just `unsigned long` - i.e. treat the pointer as an integer.

Comment: It's not casting to `unsigned long*`, but casting to `unsigned long`, the integer type. But it's not guaranteed that `unsigned long` is sufficiently large to hold all addresses, better to use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Even with `uintptr_t`, it's not actually guaranteed for a `char* p` that `((uintptr_t)p)+1 == (uintptr_t)(p+1)`. It's very likely, though, since you would need some weird hypothetical architecture in order for the "natural" conversion between pointers and integers not to work like that. If the machine had 4-bit addressing, for example, but was forced to "fake up" an 8 bit byte in order to conform to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He says they are "both 4-byte figures"

This may well be true on a particular platform, but neither is guaranteed to be the case in general.

> But I don't get how you could do the same thing by casting it to an unsigned long* because the arithmetic will be in units of 4. What am I missing?

He is not casting to `unsigned long*`, he is casting to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  Wouldn't you be able to cast to an int then?  Why specifically unsigned long?

Comment: @AvanishGiri: `int` is not necessarily pointer-sized; `long` is the 'traditional' choice for that, and the standard recommends that `size_t` shall have no greater conversion rank than `long` if possible; on architectures with a flat address space, this generally means that you can use `long` to store addresses if the recommendation is followed; however, not all platforms - Win64 probably being the most important one - do follow it; the lack of an integer type of as least pointer size was recognized as a defect and lead to the introduction of `(u)intptr_t`

Answer (score 0):

The statement may be true on that professor's particular machine on a particular Tuesday of last year, but in general, it's wrong. If `char *` and `unsigned long` could be treated the same, C wouldn't need two distinct types.

What the professor probably wanted to say is the following rule:

For a variable of any pointer type (except `void` pointers), the following holds: `p + 1 == (T*) (((char*)p) + sizeof(*p))` (where `T` is the type of `*p`), i.e. adding 1 to a pointer increases it by the size of the type that it points to.

Since `sizeof(char) == 1`, `x+1` will have the same value if `x` is of type `char *` or `unsigned long`, given that `sizeof(char *) == sizeof(unsigned long)`, which is not to assume unless "you know what you're doing".

Note that the actual representation might differ for various reasons, most notably since `unsigned long` may have padding bits anywhere in its representation.

Comment: Steve: Arr! That's what I meant, but I certainly failed to express it correctly.